# Exporting result to csv in the middle of a cypher query

Tags: postgresql, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to export the results of a query to csv and still re-use the values from the query result as inputs for the second stage of the query.

I submit an initial query in my postgres database and pass the results to neo4j using `apoc.load.jdbc`. I've been trying to export the results for this postgres query using `apoc.export.csv.query` and then use values from the postgres query as search criteria for my cypher query.

This query works without any attempt to write to csv:

```
CALL apoc.load.jdbc('postgresql_url', 'SELECT paper_id FROM papers LIMIT 1') YIELD row
MATCH (n:paper)<-[r:REFERENCES]-(m:paper) WHERE n.paper_id = row.paper_id
RETURN n, m
```

Ideally, I'd like a query that does something likes this:

```
CALL apoc.load.jdbc('postgresql_url', 'SELECT paper_id FROM papers LIMIT 1') YIELD row
CALL apoc.export.csv.query('row', 'export/degree0.csv', {}) YIELD row
MATCH (n:paper)<-[r:REFERENCES]-(m:paper) WHERE n.paper_id = row.paper_id
RETURN n, m
```

This query returns and error that it `row.paper_id` is not defined.

I'm trying to get the results of the postgres query written to a csv and use data from that query result in the cypher query.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible you are overriding the row variable. 
you can try removing the 'YIELD row' from the export.csv in the second line.

if it doesn't work I would suggest removing also the match line and just Return *, so you can see exactly what the row variable contains.